# Using all resources in Apache Spark with Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am using Apache Spark with Yarn client.
I have 4 worker PCs with 8 vcpus each  and 30 GB of ram in my spark cluster. 
Im set my executor memory to 2G and number of instances to 33. 
My job is taking 10 hours to run and all machines are about 80% idle.

I dont understand the correlation between executor memory and executor instances.  Should I have an instance per Vcpu? Should I set the executor memory to be memory of machine/#executors per machine?

Comment: How about the memory utilization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using cassandra as our data source for spark.  The problem was there were not enough partitions.  We needed to split up the data more.  Our mapping for # of cassandra partitions to spark partitions was not small enough and we would only generate 10 or 20 tasks instead of 100s of tasks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you have to use the following command:

`spark-submit --num-executors 4 --executor-memory 7G --driver-memory 2G --executor-cores 8 --class \"YourClassName\" --master yarn-client`

Number of executors should be 4, since you have 4 workers. The executor memory should be close to the maximum memory that each yarn node has allocated, roughly ~5-6GB (I assume you have 30GB total RAM).

You should take a look on the spark-submit parameters and fully understand them.

Comment: From the OP I understand each PC has 30G memory