# Allow only one driver to execute on spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

We have a spark cluster of 8 nodes. Each hour a spark job is submitted to the cluster. How can I configure the cluster or write some code that doest not allow a spark job to be submitted on the cluster if one is already running there?

Comment: you can use Spark JobServer (https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) to check if the job is running and trigger only if all conditions for trigger are met..

Comment: What scheduler are you using? YARN, Mesos or standalone?

Answer (score 1):

Is it pertinent that job shouldn't submit?

A better way, in my opinion, would be to allocate all the resources of the cluster to each job while submitting it using `executorMemory`, `executorCores` and other properties.

You may also change your scheduling mechanism from fair scheduling to something else.

What this will do essentially is, if a job is already running, your cluster will not have any resources to allocate to another job if executed and the new job will go in the wait state, till the resources are free.

PS: Search for workflow managers. OOzie, azkaban etc maybe of help to you.

Let me know if this helps.
Cheers.

Comment: I dont want the submitted job to be in 'WAITING' state. Because as soon as the running job finishes the 'WAITING' job will start executing.

Answer (score 0):

We can check the cluster states first.

if there's no jobs running, then you can submit your new job.

Eg: modify script bin/spark-submit, and add a check before calling sparkSubmit

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to deal with this is to always assign all the cluster resources to the job when you submit it, which is probably what you want to achieve by having one job running at any single time.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457314/using-all-resources-in-apache-spark-with-yarn) can give you some guidance on the flags and options to set on the command line to make this happen (but make sure to adjust those flags according to the needs of your specific scheduler, be it YARN, Mesos or the standalone one).